# How to do indexing of a NumPy 3D-array based on 2D-array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let say I have a NumPy array `A` of shape (66,5) and `B` of shape (100, 66, 5).

The elements of `A` will index the first dimension (`axis=0`) of `B`, where the values are from 0 to 99 (i.e. the first dimension of `B` is 100).

```
A = 
array([[   1,    0,    0,    1,    0],
       [   0,    2,    0,    2,    4],
       [   1,    7,    0,    5,    5],
       [   2,    1,    0,    1,    7],
       [   0,    7,    0,    1,    4],
       [   0,    0,    3,    6,    0]
       ....                         ]])
```

For example, A[4,1] will take index 7 of the first dimension of `B`, index 4 of the second dimension of `B` and index 1 of the third dimension `B`.

What I wanted to is to produce array `C` of shape (66,5) where it contains the elements in `B` that are selected based on the elements in `A`.

Comment: A toy example would help us understand better. Is `A` a boolean mask or index array? and when you say `axis=0` do you mean the first element or first dimension? (axis refers to dimension and I cannot see how a 2-D index on all elements of axis=0 of 3-D array will result in a 2-D array.

Comment: @Ehsan It is hard to give a toy example. But, I have tried my best to explain in the edit.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) to do that:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(100, size=(66, 5))
b = np.random.random(size=(100, 66, 5))
c = np.take_along_axis(b, a[np.newaxis], axis=0)[0]
# Test some element
print(c[25, 3] == b[a[25, 3], 25, 3])
# True
```

Comment: What is `[0]` at the end of `c = np.take_along_axis(b, a[np.newaxis], axis=0)[0]`?

Comment: @Aqee `np.take_along_axis` requires both arguments to have the same number of dimensions, although they can be broadcasted. So, I add an initial singleton dimension to `a` with `[np.newaxis]`, and then the result is `(1, 66, 5)`, so I squeeze out that dimension from the result with `[0]`. It would have been equivalent to do `np.expand_dims(a, 0)` and `np.squeeze(np.take_along_axis(...), 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for advances indexing of first dimension of `B`. You can use `np.indices` to create the indices required for the other two dimensions of `B` and use advanced indexing:

```
idx = np.indices(A.shape)
C = B[A,idx[0],idx[1]]
```

Example:

```
B = np.random.rand(10,20,30)
A = np.array([[   1,    0,    0,    1,    0],
       [   0,    2,    0,    2,    4],
       [   1,    7,    0,    5,    5],
       [   2,    1,    0,    1,    7],
       [   0,    7,    0,    1,    4],
       [   0,    0,    3,    6,    0]])

print(C[4,1]==B[7,4,1])
#True
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following (using functions of `NumPy` library):

```
print(A)
# array([[2, 0],
#        [1, 1],
#        [2, 0]])

print(B)
# array([[[ 5,  7],
#         [ 0,  0],
#         [ 0,  0]],

#        [[ 1,  8],
#         [ 1,  9],
#         [10,  1]],

#        [[12, 22],
#         [ 2,  2],
#         [ 2,  2]]])

temp = A.reshape(-1) + np.cumsum(np.ones([A.reshape(-1).shape[0]])*B.shape[0], dtype = 'int') - 3
C = B.swapaxes(0, 1).swapaxes(2, 1).reshape(-1)[temp].reshape(A.shape)

print(C)
# array([[12,  7],
#        [ 1,  9],
#        [ 2,  0]])
```

Comment: I would suggest adding explanation on what your code does.

Comment: Hopefully, you can explain what you suggested

Comment: It does what you asked for. I have added an example, do check.